# ¿Como puedo hacer que cuando no haya conexión rediriga los que no dan conexión a un txt?

Tags: bash

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando hacer que mi script cuando una IP de las que puesto un rango por ejemplo: 10.0.2.0 a 10.0.2.10 y de las que estan caidas durante el script reenviarlas a un fichero txt

Esto es lo que tengo

```
while read line
do
    echo $line
    ping -c 5 $line
    if [ $line -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Hay conexión"
    else
       echo "No hay conexión" >> enviarip.txt
    fi
done < ip.txt 
ssmtp correo < enviarip.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces va bastante bien. Quizás tu asunto está en cómo funciona el comando `ping` y cómo hacer para que se pueda salir fácilmente.

Una opción es utilizar `-c 1` para enviar tan sólo un paquete, además de `-W 1` para esperar la respuesta durante sólo un segundo:

```
$ ping "$direccion" -q -c1 -W1 &> /dev/null
```

En un script, te puede funcionar así:

```
#!/bin/bash

export file_encendidas='./encendidas.log'
export file_apagadas='./apagadas.log'

declare -a direcciones=(
    #[START] No existen. 
    #  Tendrían que dar error, además,
    #+ se tendrían que registrar en el archivo
    #+ "apagadas.log"
    120.0.0.1
    120.0.0.2
    120.0.0.3
    #[END] No existen

    #[START] Si exsten. 
    #  Tendrían que resultar correctas, además,
    #+ se tendrían que registrar en el archivo
    #+ "encendidas.log"
    es.stackoverflow.com
    google.com
    google.com.mx
    #[END] Si existen
)

#  Esta es la función donde ocurre la prueba 
#+ con cada dirección IP.
test_ip() {
    declare -l direccion="$1"
    
    if ping "$direccion" -q -c1 -W1 &> /dev/null
    then echo "$direccion" >> "$file_encendidas"
    else echo "$direccion" >> "$file_apagadas"
    fi
}
export -f test_ip

tr " " "\n" <<< "${direcciones[@]}" | xargs -P0 -I {} bash -c 'test_ip {}'

# Sólo para verificar el contenido
head *.log
```

Resultando en:

```
$ ./revisar.sh
==> apagadas.log <==
120.0.0.1
120.0.0.2
120.0.0.3

==> encendidas.log <==
google.com
google.com.mx
es.stackoverflow.com
```

En tu caso, no es necesario hacer un array; sólo lo hice para propósitos de ejemplo. En lugar de un array, tan sólo alimenta `xargs` con el contenido de tu archivo de direcciones.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. También puedes usar un operador ternario y hacer algo así como `ping "$direccion" -q -c1 -W1 &>/dev/null && echo "bla" >>f1 || echo "no" >> f2`

Comment: @fedorqui Toda la razón; pero en esta semana vi un artículo sobre algunas malas prácticas por utilizar && y || como sustituto de if else. Eso me tiene un tanto consternado y ando poniendo en orden mis ideas. Claro que para cuestiones simples no ve inconveniente en usarlo; pero mi consternación no aún no cesa.

Comment: https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/if-statement/#why-you-should-not-use-the--and--operators-instead-of-a-bash-if-statement

Comment: qué buena la referencia. Me la apunto para leerla con calma durante el día. Muchas gracias por el enlace y por hacernos a todos aprender con tus respuestas (y qué buena la sensación de consternación cuando leemos cosas así :D)

Answer (score 0):

Ping devuelve un código de error en caso de que haya fallado y 0 cuando todo ha ido bien.

```
ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
echo $? # 0

ping -c 1 192.168.200.200 1>/dev/null 2>&1
echo $? # 2
```

En este caso `1>/dev/null 2>&1` es para que no saque stdout o stderr por pantalla

Comment: Como hago para poder enviar por ssmtp los que no dan conexion?

Comment: @JosepGiner Eso es material para otra pregunta. En caso de que la respuesta de nax te haya funcionado, puedes marcarla como positiva para que otros la puedan encontrar con mayor facilidad.